# Alpha property of UIImageview not set in Custom UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have made a subclass of UITableviewCell which consists of multiple UIimageview.
I am animating the alpha property of that UIImageviews. Initially I set alpha property of that Imageviews to 0 and then in animation block set alpha property to 1. 
My problem is that when again I reload that cell, it first shows all imageviews, then their alpha property is set to 0 and hence in animation block again it is set to 1.Is there any way that when I reload that particular cell , so before it is shown , I set its alpha property to zero.

```
    class EditProfileTableviewCell:UITableViewCell{
        @IBOutlet weak var ibUpdatePicImageVIew: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var ibUpdatePicImageview3: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var ibUpdatePicImageview2: UIImageView!

        override func prepareForReuse() {
            print("reuse called")
            if let _ = ibUpdatePicImageVIew, _ = ibUpdatePicImageview2 {
                print("initial configuration")
               ibUpdatePicImageVIew.alpha = 0
               ibUpdatePicImageVIew.alpha2 = 0
               ibUpdatePicImageVIew.alpha3 = 0
            }
        }
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            print("loaded")

            if let _ = ibUpdatePicImageVIew, _ = ibUpdatePicImageview2 {
                print("initial configuration")
               ibUpdatePicImageVIew.alpha = 0
               ibUpdatePicImageVIew.alpha2 = 0
               ibUpdatePicImageVIew.alpha3 = 0

            }

        }
    }

    // willDisplayCell Method

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

 delay(0.2, closure: {
                        let frame = cell.ibUpdatePicImageVIew.frame
                        cell.ibUpdatePicImageVIew.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

                   cell.ibUpdatePicImageVIew.alpha = 0
                   cell.ibUpdatePicImageVIew.alpha2 = 0
                   cell.ibUpdatePicImageVIew.alpha3 = 0

                        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                            cell.ibUpdatePicImageVIew.frame = frame
                            cell.ibUpdatePicImageVIew.alpha = 1

                        })
                    })

    }
```

Comment: prepareForReuse Should be called each time

Comment: @Wain I have overridden it, so it is being called everytime

Comment: So it should reset the alpha before display

Comment: Yes but it is not happening

Comment: Is this when you scroll slow or fast?

Comment: It doesn't depend on scroll, Actually during reload I am using different cells over it. So the issue is this that the cell containing UIImageviews are already there in memory and when i call them again using reuse identifier it first shows the cell's imageviews with alpha = 1 and then whole animation process runs like sets it to 0 and later set alpha to 1.

Comment: Calling reload data on the table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112685/discussion-between-na000022-and-wain).